# Angular filter between two times validation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have added my full code .here user selected day is Wednesday(Wed Dec 02 2015) and time 09:00 PM .if i check with shop in that wednesday open and close time(09:10 AM - 06:30 PM).here when i click order button it should show shop closed now instead of its showing shop open now.

here for am timings everything is working if time is pm means its always showing shop opened now.some one help me out
check this below condition

var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 09:00 PM"  --- it should show closed now

var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 06:40 PM"  ---it should show closed now

var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 09:00 AM"  ---it should show closed now(its working perfectly)

var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 10:00 AM"  ---it should show opened now(its working perfectly)

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/62/)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myCntrl", function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.isOpen = function(dealerSchedule) {
 
  var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 09:00 PM",
       date = new Date(d),
       times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[date.getDay() - 1]].split(" - "),
        startTime = new Date(date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + " " + times[0]),
        endTime = new Date(date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + " " + times[1]),
        response = false;
      
      date = $scope.convertToUTC(date);
      startTime = $scope.convertToUTC(startTime);
   endtime = $scope.convertToUTC(endTime);
   response = startTime <= date && endTime >= date;
      if(response){
        alert('shop opened now'); 
    }else{
       alert('sorry shop closed');
     }
    };
  
  $scope.convertToUTC = function(date){
    return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
  }

 
    $scope.dealers = [{

       S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        status:"",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10 AM - 12:00 PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "thursday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "friday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "saturday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM",
        "sunday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM"
      },
    },  ]
    //var date = new Date();

    //$scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
    //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <label>Search on Label</label>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">

      {{dealer.Store_Name}}
      <br>{{dealer.S_Email_id}}
      <br>wednesday :{{dealer.Day.wednesday}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="order" ng-click="isOpen(dealer.Day)"/>
          
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the solution you need not to convert the time to UTC for comaparison .. :)

```
        <html>
            <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp">
              <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
                <label>Search on Label</label>
                <br>
                <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
                <br>
                <br>

                <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">

                  {{dealer.Store_Name}}
                  <br>{{dealer.S_Email_id}}
                  <br>wednesday :{{dealer.Day.wednesday}}
                  <br>
                  <input type="button" value="order" ng-click="isOpen(dealer.Day)"/>

                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            angular.module('myApp', [])
              .controller("myCntrl", function($scope, $filter) {

                $scope.isOpen = function(dealerSchedule) {

                    var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 09:00 PM",
                    date = new Date(d),
                    times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[date.getDay() - 1]].split(" - "),


                startTime = new Date(date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + " " + times[0]),
                endTime = new Date(date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + " " + times[1]),
                response = false;

                    console.log(endTime+"entime");
                    console.log(startTime+"statrt",date)

                  response = startTime <= date && endTime >= date;
                  if(response){
                alert('shop opened now'); 
                      }else{
                      alert('sorry shop closed');
                    }
                };

              $scope.convertToUTC = function(date){
                return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
              }


                $scope.dealers = [{

                   S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
                S_Store: "samsung",
                status:"",
                Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
                S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
                Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
                Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
                  Day: {
                "monday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "tuesday": "09:10 AM - 12:00 PM",
                "wednesday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "thursday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "friday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "saturday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM",
                "sunday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM"
                  },
                },  ]
                //var date = new Date();

                //$scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
                //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
              })
            </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: nothing is working my concern press that order button for this condtion var d = "Wed Dec 02 2015 09:00 PM" --- it should show closed now

Comment: Pls change it to pm i have taken am

Comment: one more thing if wednesday shop "wednesday": "Holiday", means.it's passing invalide date

Comment: Day: {
                "monday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "tuesday": "09:10 AM - 12:00 PM",
                "wednesday": "Leave",
                "thursday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "friday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
                "saturday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM",
                "sunday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM"
                  },
                },